# Vue.js Problem Controlling Div with v-show

Tags: vue.js

I have four buttons and corresponding four divisions. On clicking first button, I want to display first div, on clicking the second button, I want to display the second div, and so on.

The button click event calls a method with the division number (0 through 3)
`@click="showDiv(0)"` for first button and `@click="showDiv(1)"` for the second button. This is my showDiv() method 
showDiv: function(divNumber)

```
showDiv: function(divNumber)
{
        this.showDetailsDiv.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
              array[index]=null;
            });
            this.showDetailsDiv[divNumber] = true; 
            console.log(this.ShowDetailsDiv);
}
```

The initial value of showDetailsDiv prop is array with null values

```
showDetailsDiv: [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
```

In template, I am trying to control the divisions through v-show

```
    <div v-show="showDetailsDiv[0]">
       First div
    </div>
    <div v-show="showDetailsDiv[1]">
       Second div
    </div>  
   <div v-show="showDetailsDiv[2]">
       Third div
    </div>
```

When I click the button, I see that the corresponding element of showDetailsDiv is changing to true, however, the corresponding division does not display. Is there anything wrong in my logic?

When I try to control the display of division using direct properties (e.g. showDiv0, showDiv1, showDiv2 & showDiv3) with the following code, it works.

```
showDiv: function(divNumber)
{
    this.showDetailsDiv.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
      array[index]=null;
    });
    this.showDetailsDiv[divNumber] = true; 
    console.log(this.showDetailsDiv);

    this.showDiv0= false; 
    this.showDiv1= false; 
    this.showDiv2= false; 
    this.showDiv3= false; 
    let elementID = 'showDiv' + divNumber;
    this[elementID] = true;
}

 <div v-show="showDiv0">
       First div
    </div>
    <div v-show="showDiv1">
       Second div
    </div>  
   <div v-show="showDiv2">
       Third div
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want only one element to be visible at the same time?

Comment: Yes, only one div to be visible at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. Template should look like:

```html
   <div v-show="visible == 0">
       First div
    </div>
    <div v-show="visible == 1">
       Second div
    </div>  
   <div v-show="visible == 2">
       Third div
    </div>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        visible: null,
    }
}
```

You can simplify `showDiv` method to:

```js
showDiv: function(divNumber) {
    this.visible = divNumber;
}
```

You can also add method `isVisible` to check which div is visible:

```js
isVisible(divNumber) {
    return this.visible == divNumber;
}
```

and use it like:

```html
<div v-show="isVisible(0)">
    First div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change an array element directly, Vue won't be able to detect the changes due to JavaScript limitations. You should be able to do it using the corresponding array method:

```
this.showDetailsDiv.splice(divNumber, 1, true);
```

You can find more ways of doing it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods

Also, if `showDetailsDiv` is a prop, you should probably avoid modifying it and create a copy in the component data instead.